# I keep getting the error "Unable to validate the information provided" when I try to sign up with the TypingDNA integration

Tags: c#, xml, azure

I have followed the steps dictated in https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/partner-integrations/tree/master/samples/TypingDNA.

I have modified the following areas:
(1) yourtenant
(2) b2ccustompage
(3) typingdnainterface

I have done the following:
(1) Hosted the Typing-DNA API interface
(2) Hosted the HTML files
(3) Added codes to TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml to allow javascript execution

**TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml**

```
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" TenantId="yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com" PolicyId="B2C_1A_TDNA_TrustFrameworkExtensions" PublicPolicyUri="http://yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_TDNA_TrustFrameworkExtensions" TenantObjectId="d6f33888-948c-4c1f-9b50-1590f171fc7">
  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="tdnaid">
        <DisplayName>TypingDNAId</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="checkUserCount">
        <DisplayName>checkUserCount</DisplayName>
        <DataType>int</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="checkUserSuccess">
        <DisplayName>checkUserSuccess</DisplayName>
        <DataType>int</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="typingpattern">
        <DisplayName>collected typing pattern</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
        <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="netscore">
        <DisplayName>tdna netscore returned</DisplayName>
        <DataType>int</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="hashedId">
        <DisplayName>hashedId for tdna</DisplayName>
        <DataType>string</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="promptMFA">
        <DisplayName>flag returned for MFA prompt by TDNA</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
      <ClaimType Id="saveTypingPattern">
        <DisplayName>flag returned for save pattern after verify</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>

    <ClaimsTransformations>
      <ClaimsTransformation Id="HashObjectIdWithEmail" TransformationMethod="Hash">
        <InputClaims>
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectid" TransformationClaimType="plaintext" />
          <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" TransformationClaimType="salt" />
        </InputClaims>
        <InputParameters>
          <InputParameter Id="randomizerSecret" DataType="string" Value="B2C_1A_tdnaHashedId" />
        </InputParameters>
        <OutputClaims>
          <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hashedId" TransformationClaimType="hash" />
        </OutputClaims>
      </ClaimsTransformation>
    </ClaimsTransformations>
        <ContentDefinitions>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.error">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:globalexception:1.2.0</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.0</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.idpselections.signup">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:providerselection:1.2.0</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.signuporsignin">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:unifiedssp:1.2.0</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.profileupdate">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountsignup">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:1.2.0</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.phonefactor">
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:multifactor:1.2.0</DataUri>
      </ContentDefinition>

        <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.tdnasignup">
        <LoadUri>https://b2ccustompage.blob.core.windows.net/b2ccustompage/selfAssertedSignUp.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.0.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
      <ContentDefinition Id="api.selfasserted.tdnasignin">
        <LoadUri>https://b2ccustompage.blob.core.windows.net/b2ccustompage/selfAssertedSignIn.cshtml</LoadUri>
        <RecoveryUri>~/common/default_page_error.html</RecoveryUri>
        <DataUri>urn:com:microsoft:aad:b2c:elements:contract:selfasserted:2.0.0</DataUri>
        <Metadata>
          <Item Key="DisplayName">Collect information from user page</Item>
        </Metadata>
      </ContentDefinition>
    </ContentDefinitions>
  </BuildingBlocks>
  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>TDNA REST APIs</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-TDNA-CheckUser"> 
          <DisplayName>Check user in TDNA</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://typingdnainterface.azurewebsites.net/api/tdna/getuser</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="HashObjectIdWithEmail" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hashedId" PartnerClaimType="objectId"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="checkUserSuccess" PartnerClaimType="success" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="checkUsercount" PartnerClaimType="count" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-TDNA-SaveUser">
          <DisplayName>Save user in TDNA</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://typingdnainterface.azurewebsites.net/api/tdna/save</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="HashObjectIdWithEmail" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hashedId" PartnerClaimType="objectId"/>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="typingpattern" />
          </InputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="REST-TDNA-VerifyUser">
          <DisplayName>Save user in TDNA</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://typingdnainterface.azurewebsites.net/api/tdna/verify</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
            <!-- Set AuthenticationType to Basic or ClientCertificate in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <!-- REMOVE the following line in production environments -->
            <Item Key="AllowInsecureAuthInProduction">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <InputClaimsTransformations>
            <InputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="HashObjectIdWithEmail" />
          </InputClaimsTransformations>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="hashedId" PartnerClaimType="objectId"/>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="typingpattern" />
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="checkUsercount" PartnerClaimType="count" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="netscore" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="promptMFA" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="saveTypingPattern" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>


    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>SUSI TDNA Integrated</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email-TDNA">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"/>
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.tdnasignin</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName"/>
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="typingpattern"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="netscore"/>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="promptMFA" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="saveTypingPattern" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive"/>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-TDNA-CheckUser" ContinueOnError="false"/>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-TDNA-VerifyUser"/>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-TDNA-SaveUser">
                            <Preconditions>
                                <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                                    <Value>saveTypingPattern</Value>
                                    <Value>False</Value>
                                    <Action>SkipThisValidationTechnicalProfile</Action>
                                </Precondition>
                            </Preconditions>
                        </ValidationTechnicalProfile>
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD"/>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-TDNA">
          <DisplayName>Email signup</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="IpAddressClaimReferenceId">IpAddress</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.selfasserted.tdnasignup</Item>
            <Item Key="language.button_continue">Create</Item>
            <Item Key="EnforceEmailVerification">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <CryptographicKeys>
            <Key Id="issuer_secret" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_TokenSigningKeyContainer" />
          </CryptographicKeys>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="Verified.Email" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="reenterPassword" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="executed-SelfAsserted-Input" DefaultValue="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="typingpattern"/>
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail-TDNA" />
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-TDNA-CheckUser" ContinueOnError="true"/>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="REST-TDNA-SaveUser"/>
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
        <TechnicalProfile Id="AAD-UserWriteUsingLogonEmail-TDNA">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="Operation">Write</Item>
            <Item Key="RaiseErrorIfClaimsPrincipalAlreadyExists">false</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
            <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" Required="true" />
          </InputClaims>
          <PersistedClaims>
            <!-- Required claims -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" PartnerClaimType="signInNames.emailAddress" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newPassword" PartnerClaimType="password"/>
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" DefaultValue="unknown" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="passwordPolicies" DefaultValue="DisablePasswordExpiration" />
 
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="Verified.strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" PartnerClaimType="strongAuthenticationPhoneNumber" />
 
            <!-- Optional claims. -->
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
            <PersistedClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
          </PersistedClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="newUser" PartnerClaimType="newClaimsPrincipalCreated" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="localAccountAuthentication" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="userPrincipalName" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInNames.emailAddress" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <IncludeTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="AAD-Common" />
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>
  <UserJourneys>
    <UserJourney Id="SignUpTDNA">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail-TDNA" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

      

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWriteWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWritePhoneNumberUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>

    <UserJourney Id="SignInTDNA">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.selfasserted.tdnasignin">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email-TDNA" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

Comment: See troubleshooting.  the schema may not be correct : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-overview

Comment: May I know which portion is incorrect? I've been looking through the schema but can't seem to find anything. I used the exact same policy file as the sample provided in the GitHub repo

Comment: I don't have access to the URI schema location.  Not sure why.  The schema is at a Microsoft Webpage and I should have access.  I think you created a custom PolicyId and need a schema for the PolicyId.  Not sure.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/buildingblocks

Comment: sorry i'm still not that good at policies. does it help if i provide you with the URL for the demo that I found in the github repo?
Demo: https://b2cprod.b2clogin.com/b2cprod.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p=B2C_1A_SU_TDNA&client_id=51d907f8-db14-4460-a1fd-27eaeb2a74da&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms/&scope=openid&response_type=id_token&prompt=login

GitHub repo: https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/partner-integrations/tree/master/samples/TypingDNA

Comment: Try Testing Custom Policy Here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tutorial-create-user-flows?pivots=b2c-custom-policy&tabs=applications

Comment: Hi! Yeap the custom policy in the starter pack worked :) 
I used the pack with mfa enabled and everything went smooth