# azure B2c Seamless user migration custom policy error

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Hi I am trying to validate the users password with onprem-api.
Below is my trusted-framework base policy code.
The famework file will be avilable from the following Github link.
https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/user-migration/issues/30
I am getting below error while  executing the above policy
"Unable to validate the information provided."
Can you please help me what i am missing here.

Thanks,
Shiva

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below points:

> Unable to validate the information provided

1. This issue may occur if we put the wrong IDs or values in the extensions policy for the Identity Experience Framework and Proxy Identity Experience Frame work applications or if the extension property itself not registered successfully.
2. Please check if custom attribute for the B2C or  extension attribute is properly registered ,So that that property is used in technical profile to be validated.  [Define custom attributes in Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#modify-your-custom-policy)s
3. Please make sure the **metadata** details are all correct.To enable custom attributes in your policy,we need to  provide **Application ID and Application Object ID** before using extension property in the AAD-Common technical profile metadata. modify-your-custom-policy as such.

```html
<Metadata>
       <Item Key="ApplicationObjectId"> objectId here</Item>
         <Item Key="ClientId"> appId here</Item>
    </Metadata>
```

4. Also please check if,datatype of custom attribute  mentioned is correct and the received claim matches the data type .See [b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/issues](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/issues/34#issuecomment-598982655)

**References:**

1. [c# -"Unable to validate the information provided"DNA integration - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68234063/i-keep-getting-the-error-unable-to-validate-the-information-provided-when-i-tr)
2. [azure ad B2C force password reset. Unable to validate the information provided · Issue  GitHub](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/289)